# Arbitrary Intersection between $\mathbb{R, N, Z}$

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

I would like to understand the functionality and intuition of performing an Arbitrary Union/Intersection on sets which contain sets, i.e their elements are sets. I would like some clarity on: A set(s) vs set(s) whose elements are sets.

$ G_1= \mathbb \{R\}, \ G_2= \mathbb \{Z\} \ G_3= \mathbb \{N\}\ $

Will: $ \bigcap_{i \in I}G_i = \varnothing$

I believe it to be so, because $ \bigcup_{i \in I} G_i = \{\mathbb R, \mathbb Z, \mathbb N\} $

Glad to be clarified on this concept.

Comment: $ 0 \in \mathbb R $ is true,

Comment: I wonder if my definition of arbitrary union and intersection is on point.

Comment: I mean if $ G_3 = \{ \mathbb R \} $ would the $ card(G_3) = 1$ or $= card( \mathbb R) $? @MauroALLEGRANZA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you write
$$
G_1=\mathbb{N},\quad
G_2=\mathbb{Z},\quad
G_3=\mathbb{R}
$$
then $G_1\cap G_2\cap G_3=\mathbb{N}$ and $G_1\cup G_2\cup G_3=\mathbb{R}$ simply because $\mathbb{N}\subset\mathbb{Z}\subset\mathbb{R}$.

On the other hand if you write
$$
G_1=\{\mathbb{N}\},\quad
G_2=\{\mathbb{Z}\},\quad
G_3=\{\mathbb{R}\}
$$
then $G_1\cap G_2\cap G_3=\emptyset$ and $G_1\cup G_2\cup G_3=\{\mathbb{N},\mathbb{Z},\mathbb{R}\}$.

The difference is in the idea that a set $A$ and a set whose only element is the set $A$ are two totally different things.

Comment: Wow, this clarification is what I was pondering on!

Comment: I mean if $ G_3 = \{ \mathbb R \} $

Comment: Thanks, highly appreciate your help. To seal the deal, G1={ℝ,ℕ,ℤ} and G2={ℤ} Would G1∪G2={ℝ,ℕ,ℤ} and G1∩G2={ℤ} or ∅

Comment: My intuition is that: if the enclosed sets in Gi are treated as elements then the intersection = {ℤ} makes sense, but if it is treated as collection of sets, the two collections G1={ℝ,ℕ,ℤ} and G2={ℤ} are totally different collections

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}$ is both an element of $G_1$ and $G_2$ so it belongs to the intersection.

Answer (score 0):

We have $x\in\bigcap_{i\in I}G_i$ if and only if $x\in G_i$ for **every** $i\in I$.

In your case e.g. $1\in G_i$ for $i=1,2,3$ so that $1\in\bigcap_{i\in I}G_i=G_1\cap G_2\cap G_3=\mathbb R\cap\mathbb Z\cap\mathbb N$.

Actually for $I=\{1,2,3\}$ we have: $$\bigcap_{i\in I}G_i=G_1\cap G_2\cap G_3=\mathbb R\cap\mathbb Z\cap\mathbb N=\mathbb N$$

Likewise we have $x\in\bigcup_{i\in I}G_i$ if and only if $x\in G_i$ for **some** $i\in I$.

In your case: $$\bigcup_{i\in I}G_i=G_1\cup G_2\cup G_3=\mathbb R\cup\mathbb Z\cup\mathbb N=\mathbb R$$

---

edit (after edit of question).

If $A$ is a set then formally $\cup A$ is union of all elements of $A$.

That means that $x\in \cup A$ if and only if $x\in a$ for some $a\in A$.
Actually we have: $$\bigcup_{i\in I}G_i:=\cup\{G_i\mid i\in I\}$$ so that $x\in\bigcup_{i\in I}G_i$ iff $x\in G_i$ for some $i\in I$.

In special case where $G_i=\{A_i\}$ the expression $x\in G_i$ is the same as $x=A_i$ so in that case the following statements are equivalent:

- $x\in\bigcup_{i\in I}G_i=\bigcup_{i\in I}\{A_i\}$
- $x=A_i$ for some $i\in I$
- $x\in\{A_i\mid i\in I\}$

Showing that: $$\bigcup_{i\in I}\{A_i\}=\{A_i\mid i\in I\}$$

We also have:$$\bigcup_{i\in I}\{A_i\}=\cup\{\{A_i\}\mid i\in I\}$$

Comment: I see, and I am clarified to an extent.

Comment: if $G_2 = \mathbb C $ Would $ \mathbb N \cup \mathbb C = \mathbb C $? @mauraallegranza

Comment: Yes. If $A\subseteq B$ then automatically $A\cup B=B$. Here $\mathbb N\subseteq\mathbb C$.

Comment: I've clarified the nature of $ G_i $ Could you revisit your answer now. I wanted to understand the consequence when G is as set containing a set.

Comment: I mean if $ G_3 = \{ \mathbb R \} $ would the $ card(G_3) = 1$ or $= card( \mathbb R) $? @drhab

Comment: It would be $1$ since it contains exactly one element.

Comment: Thanks, highly appreciate your help. To seal the deal, $ G_1 = \{ \mathbb {R, N, Z} \}$ and $G_2=\{\mathbb Z\}$ Would $G_1\cup G_2 = \{ \mathbb {R, N, Z} \}$ and $G_1 \cap G_2= \{\mathbb Z \}$ or $\emptyset$

Comment: My intuition is that: if the enclosed sets in $G_i$ are treated as elements then the intersection = $\{\mathbb Z\}$ makes sense, but if it is treated as collection of sets, the two collections $ G_1 = \{ \mathbb {R, N, Z} \}$ and $G_2=\{\mathbb Z\}$ are totally different collections.

Comment: If $G_1=\{\mathbb R,\mathbb N,\mathbb Z\}$ and $G_2=\{\mathbb Z\}$ then $G_1\cup G_2=G_1=\{\mathbb R,\mathbb N,\mathbb Z\}$ and $G_1\cap G_2=G_2=\{\mathbb Z\}$.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean $I=\{1,2,3\}. $

$G_1=\{N\}$ is an abbreviation for $\forall x\;(x\in G_1\iff x=N).$ Similarly for $G_2$ and $G_3.$

Let $S=\cap_{i\in I}G_i$. What this   means is $\forall x \;(x\in S\iff \forall i\in I\;(x\in G_i)).$

In this case $I$ is finite and so is each $G_i.$ so we  have $\forall x\;(x\in S\iff (x\in G_1\land x\in G_2\land x\in G_3)),$ which is equivalent to $\forall x\;(x\in S \iff (x=N\land x =Z\land x=R)). $ Since there is no $x$ such that $x=N=Z=R,$ there is no $x\in S,$ so $$\cap_{i\in I}G_i=S=\emptyset.$$

When I wrote "Let $S=\cap_{i\in I}G_i$" I was merely defining $S$ as an abbreviation for the RHS expression. This is often done to make the rest easier to read and comprehend.

There is also the notation $\cap X,$ often written with "\bigcap" as $\bigcap X$ In this notation, $X$ is a collection of sets, and $y\in \cap X$ means that $y$  belongs to every member of that collection. Similarly there is $\cup X$, or $\bigcup X$, where $z\in \cup X$ means  $z$ belongs to at least one member of $X.$

Comment: Thanks, highly appreciate your help. To seal the deal, $ G_1 = \{ \mathbb {R, N, Z} \}$ and $G_2=\{\mathbb Z\}$ Would $G_1\cup G_2 = \{ \mathbb {R, N, Z} \}$ and $G_1 \cap G_2= \{\mathbb Z \}$ or $\emptyset$

Comment: My intuition is that: if the enclosed sets in $G_i$ are treated as elements then the intersection = $\{\mathbb Z\}$ makes sense, but if it is treated as collection of sets, the two collections $ G_1 = \{ \mathbb {R, N, Z} \}$ and $G_2=\{\mathbb Z\}$ are totally different collections.

Comment: The notation $\{X\}$  means a set withe exactly one member, and that one member is $X,$ regardless of whether or not $X$  is a set. It is an axiom of Set Theory that a set $A$ and a set $B$ are equal iff  $A$ and  have the same members; that is iff there is nothing belonging to $A$  but not to  $B$, and vice-versa.